# Error Running Neo4j with Systemd on Arch Linux

Tags: neo4j, archlinux, systemd

I've got neo4j installed on my arch linux setup, and am able to start the server manually (`sudo neo4j start`). However, when I try to start it using `systemctl start neo4j`, I get

```
Job for neo4j.service failed. See 'systemctl status neo4j.service' and
'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

Neither of the suggestions in the error message give anything helpful. I have /usr/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Neo4j

[Service]
User=root
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/neo4j start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/neo4j stop
PIDFile=/run/neo4j/neo4j-service.pid
#LimitNOFILE=40000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've tried changing the User between neo4j and root, and I originally had LimitNOFILE not commented out, before I tried setting the limits in security/limits.conf (which got rid of the file number error when starting it normally). This setup is mentioned in the AUR, but I just can't get it working. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: systemd should be capturing Neo4j's stdout. Do you see that when you run `journalctl`? Or in `/var/log/syslog`? (Or elsewhere depending on how syslog is configured.)

Do you see anything in Neo4j's own logs? Their location will depend on how you have installed Neo4j, typically under `<neo4j-root>/data`.

Comment: I didn't see anything from neo4j in any of those locations. Is the logging configured on a per service basis? Can I set systemctl to pipe it to stdout?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know Arch or systemd well enough to answer that. But I see that you've accepted the answer below, so I assume you are okay now.

Comment: It looks like the error was happening before neo4j put anything to stdout. I sorted it out and now I'm able to see the logged output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just attempted to set up Neo4j on a fresh Arch VM and this has worked successfully. The steps I followed were:

1. Boot
2. Install **wget** and **jdk7-openjdk** by running `pacman -S wget jdk7-openjdk`
3. Download Neo4j package from the AUR using `wget https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ne/neo4j/neo4j.tar.gz`
4. Unzip package with `tar xvf neo4j.tar.gz`
5. Change dir `cd neo4j`
6. Build package using `makepkg` (this downloads Neo4j from dist.neo4j.org)
7. Install with `pacman -U neo4j-2.1.5-1-any.pkg.tar.gz`
8. As per the messages received during installation, create configuration to point at the installed JDK:

   - `mkdir /etc/systemd/system/neo4j.service.d`
   - `echo "[Service]" >> /etc/systemd/system/neo4j.service.d/java_home.conf`
   - `echo "Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default" >> /etc/systemd/system/neo4j.service.d/java_home.conf`
9. Start the server with `systemctl start neo4j.service`
10. Check the server is running with `curl http://localhost:7474/db/data/`

If this works, a JSON response will be shown.

As I can't tell exactly the steps you went through to install or what your file system may look like, your best bet will probably be to compare the steps you went through with these above and see where the differences are.

At a guess, I'd recommend looking at your Java installation first to see if the service is having trouble finding the Java runtime. This is certainly the most fiddly part of the whole process.

Note: I used the JDK here but I don't see why the **jre7-openjdk** package should not work just as well.

Comment: How does it locate the java runtime when doing `neo4j start`? I ask because if I can see what it's locating that way (which seems to work), then I could compare it with what I've pointed it to in the java_home.conf.

Comment: The start scripts have several methods to detect the `java` executable, depending on platform. The packaging for Arch is maintained by a third party, not someone from Neo Technology, so you would have to contact them directly to find out why separate configuration is required. Either way, as far as I can tell, the value in `java_home.conf` should point to a directory containing a valid JVM or JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Do you try to add this modified line for file **/usr/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service** ?

```
[Unit]
Description=Neo4j

[Service]
User=neo4j
Type=forking
RuntimeDirectory=neo4j
RuntimeDirectoryMode=770
ExecStart=/usr/bin/neo4j start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/neo4j stop
ExecReload=/usr/bin/neo4j restart
RemainAfterExit=no
Restart=on-failure
PIDFile=/run/neo4j/neo4j-service.pid
LimitNOFILE=60000
TimeoutSec=600

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```